# Lequel de « mûr(e) » ou « mature » signifierait « qui est arrivé à une certaine maturité psychologique » ou autrement comment le dire/formuler ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs, formulation-idiomatique, anglicismes, attributs

Parmi les sens que [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mature/49922?q=mature#49821) donne à l'adjectif *mature* on trouve « qui est arrivé à une certaine maturité psychologique » ; [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mature) parle d'un anglicisme. On trouve rarement au lexique l'emploi de *mûr* au figuré en attribut pur (on trouve plutôt *[personne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/m%C3%BBr/53290/locution?q=m%C3%BBr#157619), homme mûr, d'âge mûr, esprit mûr, [être mur pour](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4670)* etc.) même s'il peut vouloir dire « qui fait preuve de sagesse, de raisonnement » (BDL) et au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%BBr) on le trouve entre autres vieilli et par plaisanterie dans un autre sens soit « être en âge, depuis longtemps, d'être marié ».

- L'un ou l'autre (voire les deux) des adjectifs *mature* et *mûr* est-il employé
  dans le sens de *maturité psychologique/morale* sous forme d'attribut
  simple (*il (n')est (pas) mûr/mature*) pour l'animé ? Peut-on expliquer et prendre position.
- Autrement quel(s) autres nom(s)/adjectif(s)/adverbe(s) peut-on leur
  substituer ou employer pour réaliser le sens « qui est arrivé à une certaine maturité psychologique » etc. en attribut ; ou existe-t-il une formulation idiomatique qui réalise le sens autrement qu'avec l'attribut du nom ?

Comment: J'ai dans l'idée que "mûr" était utilisé puis que "mature" l'a remplacé justement pour faire la différence. Un peu comme "appas" et "appâts". Mais ce n'est que mon idée

Answer (score 2):

*Adulte*, *accompli*, *rassis* me semblent pouvoir être apposés dans ce sens. 
*Mûr* serait très bien ; mais il me semble que le mot *rassis* serait plus juste car il insiste sur cette idée de sagesse liée à l'âge.
Exemple tiré du [TLF](http://stella.atilf.fr/) :

> Les grands travaux improvisés de M. Villemain avaient fait leur temps (...). On était devenu plus rassis et plus positif. On voulait des faits (SAINTE-BEUVE, Nouv. lundis, t. 13, 1868, p. 234).

Sinon, des expressions plus spécifiques doivent pouvoir être trouvées selon le contexte (*maître de son art, en pleine possession de ses moyens, prêt à, dans la force de*...)

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas [_rassir_](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%c3%aatre_rassis/66594?q=rassis#65854) dans ce sens-là, je pensais que c'était le p.p. de _rasseoir_, donc une découverte intéressante pour moi. Larousse en ligne donne un exemple où c'est le sens qui est qualifié : _Un homme de sens rassis_. Dirais-tu directement _il est rassis_ dans un contexte où c'est clair ? Est-ce que je dois déduire de ton propos que tu considères que ni mûr ni mature ne conviennent ?

Comment: *Mûr* serait très bien ; mais il me semble que le mot *rassis* serait plus juste car il insiste sur cette idée de sagesse liée à l'âge.

Comment: Je t'invite à ajouter ces nuances à ta réponse...

Answer (score 0):

Mature is an adjective, and a gross anglicisme.  Mur would be the correct term there.

This is not at all the same maturité, a perfectly correct *noun* in French.